# Instanciate an object on button click and use incremented name for reference variable ? (android studio, java)

Tags: java, android, variables, button, instance

In order to learn java and android app building, I am creating an app that will store players’ scores (for a real card game for example). So the number of players is not fixed.

First, I have created a class “Player”, containing an id, a name and the score.

```
public class Player {
    int idj;
    String namej;
    int scorej;

    public Player(int idj, String namej, int scorej) {
        this.idj = idj;
        this.namej = namej;
        this.scorej = scorej;
    }

    public int getIdj() {
        return idj;
    }

    public void setIdj(int idj) {
        this.idj = idj;
    }

    public String getNamej() {
        return namej;
    }

    public void setNamej(String namej) {
        this.namej = namej;
    }

    public int getScorej() {
        return scorej;
    }

    public void setScorej(int scorej) {
        this.scorej = scorej;
    }
}
```

Then I would like to create a new player each time I click a button on the UI. Here is my button that call the “newPlayer” method on click:

```
Button bT1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bT1);
bT1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        newPlayer();
    }
});
```

Here is the “newPlayer” method called by each button click. But this method doesn’t work. This method has to instanciate a player object and increment the reference variable name according to the “nbrPlayer” variable.

This var is counting the number of players :

```
public int nbrPlayer = 1;
```

And this is the "newPlayer" method :

```
private void newPlayer(){

player(nbrPlayer) = new Player(nbrPlayer,"var1FromEditText"," var2FromEditText ");

nbrPlayer ++;

}
```

Thanks for your help. (I am eventually looking for a good tutorial for that but for now I did not find one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your activty where you have the button you must have a counter
your code will be like this:

```
int counter = 1;
Button bT1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bT1);
bT1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Player(counter++,"var1FromEditText"," var2FromEditText ");
    }
});
```

there is no reason to have a method newPlayer since you are not returing the player so it will die after creation.

your question is not clear where you are planning to show this players at all. so even in my solution the player is created in the button click but nothing happens with it...

you must add it to a list or set or show somewhere

Comment: Thanks. 
Yep, my counter is “public int nbrPlayer = 1;”
But I don't understand why it is not necessary in your solution to add a reference variable to the player instance. I learned earlier that we always have to do something like “MyClass myRefVar = new MyClass(arguments);”. But I am probably wrong.
Then, to answer your question, I am planning next to inflate two TextView per player in order to show their names and scores on the UI, and to add buttons in order to increment/decrement the scores. That’s all. 

Answer (score 1):

Each time when a new player hits the button, you should create instance of a player by passing id, name and score. Like this

Player newPlayer = new Player(nbrPlayer,"playerName",0);

But in your code you are not storing nbrPlayer value, so you cannot retrieve the value when that instance is dead. So you should store it in any storage to retrieve it back. I used shared preference to store that value. Check my code

```
private void newPlayer(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "MY_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int nbrPlayer = prefs.getInt("idj", 0);
    if(nbrPlayer==0){
        nbrPlayer = 1;
    }
    Player newPlayer = new Player(nbrPlayer,"playerName",0);
    nbrPlayer ++;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("idj", nbrPlayer);
    editor.apply();
    Log.d(TAG,"Player:"+nbrPlayer);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer that moves me to the next step! For now, this solution appears complex to me but I have to work on it next. I thought it was sufficient to just instantiate objects (players) to keep the values. So here I learned that we have also to store the values (id, name and score) somewhere. Before that, I was wondering if it would be a good (or simple) idea to store my players in a kind of 3-columns table (ids, names and scores) ?…